# $a-b \nmid a^2+b^2$ if $a>b+2$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Any two co-prime number $a,b$ with $a>b+2$ we have $a^2+b^2$ is not divisible by $a-b$, $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. 
But how to prove this?

Comment: Negating $b$ in the dupe proofs yields what you desire.

Comment: Here the result follows form your question but this is not exactly what your question was.!

Comment: The dupe (with $b$ negated) shows $\,(a-b,a^2+b^2)\mid 2\,$ so if $\,a-b\mid a^2+b^2$ then the gcd $= a-b \mid 2,\,$ contra $a-b > 2.\,$ That $\,1= (a,b)\,\Rightarrow\, 1= (a,b^2)=(a,a^2+b^2)\,$ is immediate from Euclid. By symmetry $(b,a^2+b^2)=1.\,$ This and related results are also proved in *many* other questions. Please search before posing common questions.

Comment: I got that. I searched but I did not get. So I had the post. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You can search using approach0, e.g. [this search.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E2%2Bb%5E%7B2%5C%20%7D%24%2C%20gcd&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a-b \mid a^2+b^2$ then $\gcd(a^2+b^2,a-b)=a-b \ge 3$. Now
$$
\gcd(a^2+b^2,a-b)=\gcd(a^2+b^2-(a-b)^2,a-b)=\gcd(2ab,a-b).
$$
Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then every prime dividing $a$ or $b$ cannot divide $a-b$. Hence
$$
\gcd(a^2+b^2,a-b) \in \{1,2\}.
$$
In particular, your conjecture is true.

Comment: Thanks Paolo. I got that.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a-b$ divides $a^2-b^2$, if it also divides $a^2+b^2$ then $a-b$ divides $2b^2$.

Now use that $a$ and $b$ are coprime to see that $a-b$ and $b^2$ are coprime. So by Euclides' lemma $a-b$ divides $2$. This contradicts the condition $a-b>2$.